# How to specify MSDeploy parameters from MSbuild

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I have a web application that I am trying to deploy and have the web.config file parametrised.
I can build the package by running

`msbuild myproj.csproj /T:package`

now when it produces the package, i get a file in the directory.

`Archive.SetParameters.Xml`

This file has Parameters in it that if I change they would end up in the deployed package.  My Question is, how can i define more parameters so that when I build the project it has my extra parameters in the file.

I belive i could do it using `MSDeploy -declareParam`  But how would I do this from MSBuild? or the .csproj file.

My end goal is to have a parametrised Web.config file for deployment into multiple environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so turns out this is fairly easy, after some significant googling eventually found this post

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/07/web-deploy-parameterization-in-action.html

> VS 2010 makes your life easier by allowing you to simply drop the
>   Parameters file in the root of your web project and if a file with the
>   name Parameters.xml is found in the root of your project it passes it
>   to Web Deploy which then parameterizes your web…

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was searching for this for hours. Don't know why it is so hard to find this.