# Specifying App Pool when using Web Deploy

Tags: iis, msbuild, webdeploy

When using either online or package Web Deploy, how can I tell MSBuild to ensure that the ASP.NET site/application should use a specific App Pool after it's been deployed to IIS?

I'd like to configure the App Pool to be created if it doesn't exist.

Visual Studio 2012.3 Web Deploy does a great job of creating the application under the specified site.

Is there an MSBuild parameter that I can set, or a post-publish PowerShell script that can be configured to run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I target an already existing application pool with webdeploy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774122/how-do-i-target-an-already-existing-application-pool-with-webdeploy)