# How to create & assign Application Pool to the website deployed via WebDeploy Package

Tags: webdeploy

I would like to create application specific AppPool (e.g – Test) & assign it to the website(that's being deployed) either by webdeploy package creation process (via setparameters.xml file) or MSBuild.I have tried both options, but still no luck. Appreciate your quick help on this.

NOTE:I checked this Stack overflow sit, but did not work for me : [How do I target an already existing application pool with webdeploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774122/how-do-i-target-an-already-existing-application-pool-with-webdeploy)

---

### OPTION 1

### Action taken to resolve this issue:

Created parameters.xml file in the same project and did the following changes. I can see that the AppPool Name is reflected in SetParameters.xml file once the package is generated. But, this AppPool is NOT created on IIS once the website is deployed successfully.

---

### parameters.xml

```
<parameter name="Application Pool" description="Enter the name of the application pool." defaultvalue="Test" tags="AppPoolConfig">
    <parameterentry kind="ProviderPath" scope="appPoolConfig" match="Test"/>
    <parameterentry kind="DeploymentObjectAttribute" scope="appHostConfig" match="application/@applicationPool"/>
</parameter>
```

---

### DemoSample.SetParameters.xml

```
<setparameter name="Application Pool" value="Test"/>
```

---

### OPTION 2

### Action taken to resolve this issue:

I also added below MSBuild Commands in MSBUILD. No luck yet.
/p:IncludeIisSettings=true /p:IncludeAppPool=true

Thanks,
Sukanta