# How do I target an already existing application pool in webdeploy package created through Visual Studio

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I have already included the settings mentioned in post

- [How do I target an already existing application pool with webdeploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774122/how-do-i-target-an-already-existing-application-pool-with-webdeploy?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

still when i deploy the WCFService it gets the default application pool of the sites and not the one mentioned in parameter.xml file.
[MsDeploy command that i am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XtDF.png)

Comment: We might need a bit more info here. Can you describe your config further please ?

Comment: Hi my SetParameter.xml has below code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="matedev/TestWCF1" />
  <setParameter name="Application Pool" value="TestApp20Pool" />
</parameters>